# Connecting to a MySQL container in the same pod

Tags: php, mysql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, unix-socket

Good day,

I am using Kubernetes to run containers on the google container engine.

The idea is to run two containers in a pod. One container uses the docker mysql image, the other runs php, laravel, nginx and composer.

Locally, this works. The idea is that the php can connect to the database on localhost, and this should work if both containers are in the same pod. However, when the pod is launched, we see the following message in the log:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

The only difference is that when testing locally, I change localhost to the internal docker ip.

Thanks and good day

Comment: MySQL is configured out of the box to only connect to localhost. If you want to connect to MySQL from another IP then you have to bind MySQL to an IP other than localhost and then GRANT permissions to the MySQL users on that host

Comment: Inside a kubernetes pod, you should be able to connect two containers by using localhost, and when I test it locally, I do this by connecting trough the IP address.

So locally, they are separate containers connecting by ip. In the cluster they are in the same pod so should be able to connect through localhost.

Comment: look in the my.cnf file for "bind address" it will initially be blank or it will say "localhost". You may need to add the internal docker IP address as the bind address in my.cnf.

Comment: Here is the issue: We do not want the socket to be used at all. The php container just needs to connect to localhost. The mysql container we use is hard to modify. This means the fix is preferably a change in the connection settings of laravel.
We can connect to the mysql workbench through the external IP of the pod if we open the port.
Kubernetes documentation specifies this: containers within a Pod can all reach each other’s ports on localhost. (http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/networking.html)

Comment: you re not connecting to localhost but directly to the socket, you have to change that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a `--port` or `-P` option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use `--host` or `-h` to specify a host name value of `127.0.0.1`, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the `--protocol=TCP` option. For example:

```
shell> mysql --host=127.0.0.1
shell> mysql --protocol=TCP
```

The `--protocol` option enables you to establish a particular type of connection even when the other options would normally default to some other protocol.

The other solution is using [Kubernetes Volume](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/volumes.html) abstraction to share a path between containers. Edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on both containers' images and change `socket` location for both MySQL server and client to point to the shared directory or disk.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! We tried both methods but I think there is something we are missing. We use the standard MySQL docker image. We set the protocol and the ip in the json descriptor. This did not work, the system kept attempting to use the socket.

Afterwards, we tried your second suggestion, the shared folder.
To accomplish this we added a volume to both containers.
The error we receive is: Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Address already in use

Comment: Another approach might be to create an emptyDir volume and mount it at /var/run/mysqld on both containers.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL comes preconfigured to only support named pipe connections on the localhost, if you are going to connect to it from another logical machine you need to locate the following line in your my.cnf file...

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

and replace it with...

```
bind-address = {your network ip here}
```

Once you have enabled the bind address restart your mysql server, check the error log to ensure that no exceptions occurred with binding the address, and then login as root and create a new user account attached to that ip address which you can then use to access MySQL from any other logical machine as long as you connect to it using the IP address you defined in my.cnf.

Please note by default the root account is only accessible from the localhost so you will either need to create a new user account or alter the root account to support remote connections (not secure)

Comment: Two problems. First, because I'm doing this in the google container engine, it is impossible for me to know the internal ip address the pod will get in advance. Second, I have 2 containers in one pod. And within one pod, containers should be able to communicate over localhost, they don't even have separate ip addresses